# Get string between opening and closing curly braces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have file which contains,

```
{"value":true,"message":"fail","timestamp":1445956265,"data":"off

"value":true,"message":"error","timestamp":1445956265,"data":"off"}
```

I want to extract above 2 lines between curly braces by excluding `{` and `}`

Expected output should be like,

```
"value":true,"message":"fail","timestamp":1445956265,"data":"off

"value":true,"message":"error","timestamp":1445956265,"url":"off"
```

I am using shell script for this. how it can be done...?

Comment: What have you done it so far?

Comment: @Noproblem I used regular expression but in this file i want to also check for "value" : true

Comment: `sed 's/}//g'`, then `grep '"value":true'` ? something like that..

Comment: @snd I want **"value":true** and its whole line

Comment: @Abhishek Nehe, you could use awk, sed, grep. Can you post your shell script code?

Comment: FILE="temp.txt"
STRING='{"success":false'
while : ;do
    [[ -f "$FILE" ]] && grep -q "$STRING" "$FILE" && break

done

Comment: @Noproblem above code i used....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk

```
awk 'sub("[{}]","")' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="temp.txt"
if [[ ! -f $FILE ]]; then
        echo "File not found: $FILE"
        exit 1
fi
out=$(awk 'sub("[{}]","")' $FILE | grep '"value":true')
if [[ ! -z $out ]]; then
        for i in $out; do
                echo "i= $i"
        done
fi
```